# reference required: slope stability is an open condition

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

It is hard to find any reference which contains a proof of the following statement: slope stability is an open condition in a flat family. 
There is one I have found, '65 paper of Narasimhan and Seshadri. Is this the unique reference which proves the statement?
There are some references which prove the openness of Gieseker stability, but what I want is about slope stability.
I will be appreciate if one introduces a reference other than Narasimhan and Seshadri...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second edition of "The Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves" by Huybrechts and Lehn, the arguments in Proposition 2.3.1 which imply (for instance) that Gieseker-semistability is an open condition in families also imply the same for $\mu$-stability (this is pointed out just after Definition 3.A.1 on p. 82).